# In reactive spring security, why must the collection of issuers be non-empty when constructing a new JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver?

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

In reactive spring security there is a note on the multi-tenancy use case referred to in the [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/resource-server/multitenancy.html) as "Dynamic Tenants".  This explains how it is possible to dynamically (that is, at run time) add authentication managers with the help of an authentication manager resolver - an object that will consult either a map of authentication managers (keyed by issuer string), or a list of issuers.  In the latter case, a default authentication manager will be used.  The resolver can be created during configuration of the `SecurityWebFilterChain` like this...

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        this.addExistingIssuers();

        JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver authenticationManagerResolver =
                new JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver(allIssuers);

        return http
                .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
                .csrf(spec -> spec.disable())
                .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/actuator/**").permitAll()
                        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/public/login").permitAll()
                        .anyExchange().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                        .authenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagerResolver))
                .build();
    }
```

The first line of this method adds any pre-existing issuers (e.g. for tenants that are already in the application database).  When new tenants are added, it may be necessary to add a new issuer to the collection of issuers that was passed (by reference) to the `JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationMangerResolver`, and this achievable by providing a method like this, that can be called during new tenant creation:

```java
    public void addNewIssuer(Account acct) {
        log.debug("Adding issuer manager for account {}", acct.getName());
        this.addIssuer(
            getIssuerUrl(this.awsRegion, acct.getUserPoolId()),
            acct.getAppClientId(),
            acct.getUserPoolId());
    }
```

This all fine, but here's the thing...

Imagine you are standing up a new multi-tenant platform in which your tenants can self-serve themselves with tenancy creation.  **Surely it should be possible for the initial list of issuers to be empty** (not null, mind you ... just empty).  When the spring service starts up, it should run perfectly fine, rejecting any calls that contain JWTs because of the empty issuer list.  Then, once a tenant registers, their JWT issuer will be added to the list using the above method, and non-public calls that require authentication will work - provided they come from this new issuer.

What actually happens is that an exception is thrown (seemingly because of an Assertion!).  Hence the service fails to start up.  Here is what appears to be the offending source code of the JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver - notice the call to Assert.notEmpty(...):

```java
    /**
     * Construct a {@link JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver} using the
     * provided parameters
     * @param trustedIssuers a collection of trusted issuers
     */
    public JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver(Collection<String> trustedIssuers) {
        Assert.notEmpty(trustedIssuers, "trustedIssuers cannot be empty");
        this.authenticationManager = new ResolvingAuthenticationManager(
                new TrustedIssuerJwtAuthenticationManagerResolver(new ArrayList<>(trustedIssuers)::contains));
    }
```

I don't see why a service shouldn't start up with no trusted issuers, then incrementally acquire trusted issuers dynamically.  And which 'special' issuer should I initialise the list with when I don't (yet) have any tenants?

I tried to start a service with an empty list; I was expecting it would work and I could dynamically add new issuers as tenants got (dynamically) added to the service.

What actually happened was that the service failed to start:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.WebFluxSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setSecurityWebFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [uk/co/govbuddy/account/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception with message: trustedIssuers cannot be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:819) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:771) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:483) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:941) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at uk.co.govbuddy.account.AccountApplication.main(AccountApplication.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [uk/co/govbuddy/account/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception with message: trustedIssuers cannot be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:659) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:647) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1488) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1375) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:811) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception with message: trustedIssuers cannot be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: trustedIssuers cannot be empty
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:479) ~[spring-core-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver.<init>(JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver.java:83) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at uk.co.govbuddy.account.config.SecurityConfig.securityFilterChain(SecurityConfig.java:67) ~[classes/:na]
    at uk.co.govbuddy.account.config.SecurityConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$securityFilterChain$1(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at uk.co.govbuddy.account.config.SecurityConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at uk.co.govbuddy.account.config.SecurityConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.securityFilterChain(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    ... 42 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got this working after reading the [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/resource-server/multitenancy.html) again (!), and a bit of experimentation.

To summarise

- `JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver` has multiple constructors
- The constructor that I was using takes a collection of issuer strings
- This is a fine way to handle multi-tenant validation of bearer tokens, but **not** *dynamic* multi-tenancy, where the tenants (and therefore issuers) can come and go after the service has started up; that constructor (that accepts a collection of strings) takes an internal deep copy of the collection
- So subsequent modification of the input collection is pointless, and it follows, that the collection passed in must have at least 1 issuer string in it
- But the **good news** is that there is another constructor that accepts a 'strategy' (ie. a function) that can retrieve an Authentication Manager from a map keyed by issuer.
- this map is mutable and can be used to achieve dynamic multi-tenancy

Here's what the security config needs to have:

1. a declaration for the map of authentication managers:

```
private Map<String, ReactiveAuthenticationManager> allManagers = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

2. A SecurityWebFilterChain bean that looks something like this:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        this.addExistingManagers();

        JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver authenticationManagerResolver =
                new JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver(issuer -> Mono.justOrEmpty(allManagers.get(issuer)));

        return http
                .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
                .csrf(spec -> spec.disable())
                .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/actuator/**").permitAll()
                        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/public/login").permitAll()
                        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/public/accounts").permitAll()
                        .anyExchange().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                        .authenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagerResolver))
                .build();
    }
```

3. Note the first line of the above method, that calls this method (here I am retrieving tenants from an `accountRepository` that was autowired in):

```
    private void addExistingManagers() {
        accountRepository.findAll().stream()
                .filter(account -> !account.isDisabled())
                .forEach(account ->
                    addAuthenticationManager(allManagers, getIssuerUrl(this.awsRegion, account.getUserPoolId()))
                );
    }
```

4. The `addAuthenticationManager` method looks like this (along with a helper method to get an issuer url):

```
    private String getIssuerUrl(String region, String userPoolId) {
        return String.format("https://cognito-idp.%s.amazonaws.com/%s",region, userPoolId);
    }

    private void addAuthenticationManager(
            Map<String, ReactiveAuthenticationManager> authenticationManagers, String issuer) {

        Mono.fromCallable(() -> ReactiveJwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation(issuer))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .map(JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager::new)
                .doOnNext(authenticationManager -> authenticationManagers.put(issuer, authenticationManager))
                .subscribe();
    }
```

5. And finally, when you want to add a new `AuthenticationManager` at some later time, just call a method like this - in this case an `Account` represents the tenant, which in my case includes an AWS Cognito User Pool:

```
    public void addNewAuthenticationManager(Account acct) {
        this.addAuthenticationManager(
                allManagers,
                getIssuerUrl(this.awsRegion, acct.getUserPoolId()));
    }
```

Hopefully this helps others trying to get dynamic multi-tenancy working in reactive spring security.  It's worth noting that the constructor call to `JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver` is slightly different to that shown in the [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/resource-server/multitenancy.html), but the version above is what worked for me.

Comment: Good catch on the list copy (reason for upvote). But I think I prefer my solution with an `AuthenticationManagerResolver` bean exposing an API to add / remove trusted issuers (I updated it to make it thread safe and consider the list copy): with this solution, you can have the `MultiTenantReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver` autowired anywhere and manage trusted issuers on it.

Comment: Sure, that's a cleaner solution ... in my current solution I've just autowired the enclosing `SecurityConfig` class into other parts of my app, so I too can manage trusted issuers from anywhere ... but yes, I accept your point - it's cleaner to separate out the addition (and removal) of trusted issuers into a separate bean so that the security config doesn't leak into other parts of the app.  Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Just define your own `ReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver<ServerWebExchange>` implementation without the non empty list limitation: copy from `JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver` or use it as delegate in a proxy of your own (with a guard on empty issuer list).

Could be something like:

```java
@Component
public class MultiTenantReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver implements ReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver<ServerWebExchange> {
    private final Collection<String> trustedIssuers = new HashSet<>();

    private JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver delegate;

    @Override
    public Mono<ReactiveAuthenticationManager> resolve(ServerWebExchange context) {
        if (delegate == null) {
            return Mono.empty();
        }
        return delegate.resolve(context);
    }
    
    public synchronized void addIssuer(String issuer) {
        trustedIssuers.add(issuer);
        delegate = new JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver(trustedIssuers);
    }
    
    public synchronized void removeIssuer(String issuer) {
        trustedIssuers.remove(issuer);
        delegate = trustedIssuers.size() == 0 ? null : new JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver(trustedIssuers);
    }

}
```

You could then have this authentication manager resolver injected for configuration:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(
        ServerHttpSecurity http,
        ReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver<ServerWebExchange> authenticationManagerResolver) {

    http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.authenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagerResolver));

    ...

    return http.build();
}
```

And could also have it `@AutoWired` in the `@Controller` or `@Service` where you add and remove trusted issuers.

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class TenantsController {
    private final MultiTenantReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver authManagerResolver;

    @PostMapping("/tenants")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('TENANTS_ADMIN')")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> addTenant(@RequestBody @Valid TenantCreationDto dto) {
        authManagerResolver.addIssuer(dto.issuerUri().toString());
        return ResponseEntity.created(dto.issuerUri()).build();
    }
    
    public static record TenantCreationDto(@NotNull URI issuerUri) {}
}
```

Comment: many thanks for this.  It certainly allows the service to start up, but when I send a request (expecting a 401 because there are no issuers, so no AuthenticationManagers), I get a stack trace / 500 response.  Specifically, `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No provider found` [etc .. too long to include here but thrown from `AuthenticationWebFilter`].  I'm guessing I might need to provide a map of custom `AuthenticationManager`s (?) instead, but can't help feeling that an empty issuer list should be supported 'out of the box'.

Comment: "can't help feeling that an empty issuer list should be supported 'out of the box'" => [open an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues). "I get a stack trace / 500 response" => add an `@ExceptionHandler`